# Array Out of Bounds error while Reading 2 Column Csv File using OpenCsv

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am reading a 2 column CSV using opencsv library and I want to put those 2 columns as key-value pairs in a map. However, I am getting Array Index out of bounds exception whenever there is an empty line in CSV. Is there any way I can avoid that? This is my code:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    CSVReader csvReader;
    try (FileReader filereader = new FileReader(path)) {
        csvReader = new CSVReader(filereader);
        String[] nextRecord;
        while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            if (nextRecord[0] != null && nextRecord[1] != null) {
                map.put(nextRecord[0], nextRecord[1]);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
```

Comment: all entries in your file does not have comma. Please paste the contents of your file If its ok. Check the length of the nextRecord array before you access `nextRecord[index]`

Comment: you can avoid it by checking if line is not empty

Comment: try to use `readNextSilently` and check that `nextRecord != null && nextRecord.length > 1`

Comment: Yeah checking the length solved the issue. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array of `nextRecord` might be empty, so you need to check the length before indexing it

change

```
if(nextRecord[0]!=null && nextRecord[1]!=null){
     map.put(nextRecrod[0],nextRecord[1]);
}
```

to

```
if(nextRecord.length ==2 && nextRecord[0]!=null && nextRecord[1]!=null){
     map.put(nextRecrod[0],nextRecord[1]);
}
```